# Android apps and Websites to learn Java and C

Tags: web-apps, java, c, programming, google-apps

I am new to coding. I would like to Java and C from scratch. 
What are the apps and websites you would recommend to learn these languages? There are so many free and paid options, i am not sure which ones to pick.

Comment: A strange combination. Those two languages don't generally go together.

Comment: And why the [tag:google-apps] tag, when you don't mention it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to write programs and read books to learn programming.

To learn Java 8, use stackoverflow and write small programs. For C, same thing.

Specifically you can get the [Manning](https://www.manning.com/) material about Java 8 to learn the basics of Java 8 without confusing details about the very advanced features.

There are sites which offer you training in Java 8 but the books are better.